# Puertos seriales (java)

Tags: java

Estoy leyendo un puerto serial con la libreria javax comm y leo los datos recibidos con (`readByte`) y me llega esto: `[B@6606af90` y cuando lo leo como String (`readString`) me llegan unos simbolos (unos cuadritos).

Mi pregunta es si está mal lo que hago y como convertir esto en la informacion real que es una cadena de numeros.
Estoy trabajando con Netbeans 8.2 64 bits, probé RXTX, Gyiovinet y ninguna me funcionó.

Este el metodo donde recibo los datos del puerto:

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent spe) {
   if(spe.isRXCHAR()){
       try {
           String buffer = puerto.readString();
           System.out.println("RECIBÍ: "+buffer);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("PROBLEMAS: "+e);
       }
   }

}
```

cuand hago la lectura con `readString()` me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola que tal Mauricio. Sería bueno que pusieras algo de código. Me parece que estas imprimiendo el identificador del objeto (No estoy muy segúro que se llame así.) Puede que estés haciendo algo como `System.out.println(MiClase)` y por eso te de ese numero.

Comment: Hay una opción para editar tu respuesta y añadir tu código. De esa manera es más entendible.

Comment: lo siento no se como es

Comment: No te preocupes. Esta a  la izquierda de la pregunta por debajo del texto. Unos links gris.

Comment: bueno amigo ya creo que se ve un poco mejor la imagen es un capture de lo que recibo del puerto

Comment: Auxilio porfavor

Comment: tienes certeza de lo que se esta enviando por ese puerto serial? probablemente no sean Strings sino bytes siguiendo algun protocolo

Comment: son bytes. pero cuando los recibo como bytes me devuelve unos datos distintitos a los que envio. por ejemplo envio 251 y recibo -5, envio 230 y recibo -24